# matrix model in django

Tags: python, json, django, matrix

I want to have a matrix model in Django. For this I need some kind of CommaSeparatedFloatField, which Django doesn't have by default (only CommaSeparatedIntegerField)

After a bit of searching I found that I should serialize it to JSON. However, after reading [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/) tutorial I thougt of having a Matrix class and than Row and Member classes in the following fashion:

```
class Matrix(models.Model):
    ...

class Row(models.Model):
    matrix = models.ForeignKey(Question)

class Element(models.Model):
    row = models.ForeignKey(Row)
    matrix = models.ForeignKey(Matrix)
    valut = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

I think that this should satisfy my needs, but is this a good practise? Or should I rather serialize the input and keep it in a CharField?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a better approach would be something like

```
class Matrix(models.Model):
    ...

class Cell(models.Model):
    matrix = models.ForeignKey(Matrix)
    row = models.IntegerField()
    col = models.IntegerField()
    val = # whatever
```

It is more flexible and you can access cols and rows simply by using [values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) instead of joining tables.